# How do I send OSC over TCP from javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, tcp, osc

I'm trying to build a mobile web application that sends OSC (Open Sound Control) messages to another program (for audio synthesis) over TCP. I can't find a javascript library which will open a TCP connection to a given address. Any advice?

Comment: You can't do that with javascript alone.

Comment: I'm also trying to do this. Have you already found an answer? I'm stuck with using Flash, Java applets or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket

I am not sure though but that is closest what you can get with JS in browsers (WebKit based).

And this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much osc support js has. AS3 has pretty great support for OSC using the TUIO library:

http://bubblebird.at/tuioflash/tuio-as3-library/

If you can modify your syntax to fit, it's rather flexible, and will port to mobile easily with flex, AIR, etc...